# What does I/O redirection mean in C++?

Tags: c++

My program needs to handle the following command line argument correctly. But I don't understand what that is or how to implement it.

```
main.exe < test.txt
```

test.txt file contains:

type count: 20
solid: 6
others: 0

Comment: It's a shell feature. You'll see the `test.txt` file input through `std::cin`.

Comment: Also there are no command line arguments for `main.exe` since shell redirects the file

Answer (score 0):

In shell scripts '<' means that the content of the file or the output of a program on the right side (text.txt in your case) will be passed to the left side trough the standard input (std::cin in c++). This means you can read the file directly with std::cin.

There are others like '>' wich makes the standard output of the left be the right element.

Answer (score -1):

Processes in OS's have IO capabilities for inputting and outputting data. Standard Input in c++ is tied to std::cin, Standard Output to std::cout, and Standard Error is tied to std::cerr.

In Linux, the syntax provided means you will get the file contents in the standard input. You then can use that path to load the file and do whatever you need to do with it.

```
int main(void)
{
   std::string file, line;
   while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
   {
     file += line;
     file += "\n";
   }

   //Do what you need to do here with file contents

   return 0;
}
```

Edit: Couple adjustment based on comments, been awhile since I needed to actually write a linux program like this.

Comment: You will get the contents of the file, not its path.

Comment: These things have been around since practically [the beginning of computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) as FORTRAN in the 1950s had a similar concept. C in the 1970s defined them with the more familiar labels of "stdin".

Comment: You will get the first word (space separated token) in the file or stream.

Comment: Adjusted, should read all the file now, know the gist been awhile since I actually had to write code like the above.

Comment: Note you have now removed all information about line-endings from the input.